# Softkeyboard's "check" button vs using .unfocus()

Tags: flutter

[image]

In this video I first click on a field within the first tab, then click the soft keyboard's "check" button. This hides the soft keyboard and takes the focus away from that field. I then navigate across tabs and back to the first. No field has the focus at this point. This is the expected behavior.

In the second iteration, I click in the notes field. Without closing the soft keyboard, I then click the submit button. That button calls `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();` which hides the soft keyboard and takes the focus away from the notes field (the teal border disappears). However, at this point I click on the next tab and the soft keyboard reappears. And when I click back the first tab the notes field once again has the focus.

Why does this happen?

What underlying code does the "check button" on the keyboard call and can I wire this up to the button rater than calling the `.unfocus()` method to get the expected result?

Edit: Still no explanation. The undesirable persistent keyboard does not occur on iOS.